# Getting "Precompiling assets failed." error when deploying Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku, but getting the error below.

My Ruby/Rails versions are:

-Rails 4.0.0

-ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

I've added the 'rails_12factor' gem which was a suggested solution on another SO question, but that didn't work. I also set this to true as per another SO question, config.serve_static_assets = true, but that didn't work either.

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Invalid CSS after "...-233px -51px; }": expected "}", was ""
       (in /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
       (sass):18950
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in `expected'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1080:in `tok!'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:536:in `block'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:529:in `ruleset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in `block_child'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:frozen-ridge-4294.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:frozen-ridge-4294.git'
~/code/fusionqa%
```

Comment: you have forget to close a curly bracket in a css file see Invalid CSS after "...-233px -51px; }": expected "}", was ""

Comment: Tried to find any CSS error but no luck...

Comment: search this text 233px -51px; }" in your stylesheeets folder , you can clearly see that " sign comes after your curly braces

Answer (score 1):

you have error in your css file:

```
 Invalid CSS after "...-233px -51px; }": expected "}", was ""
       (in /tmp/build_26a3cf6f-5411-4847-a502-be0a4ee03280/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
       (sass):18950
```

fix that & run deploy again. if it still doesn't work, post back with the deployment log.

Comment: I thought to check the CSS originally too, but couldn't find a problem there. The deployment log on Heroku says:
2013-12-25T17:41:29+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
 2013-12-25T17:43:12+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app

Answer (score 0):

Had to add a '}'to the end of a css file, didn't know it was missing...